# what's wrong with the output in this Javascript function

Tags: javascript

initial value and final value of the array.
example:

```
userInput1 = 2;
userInput2 = 6;
result on screen or console = 2,3,4,5,6
```

First I create an empty array

I think the second function with 2 parameters which are the variables entered by the user

This is my code.

```
var inicioArreglo = Number(prompt("Escribe el elmento con el que INICIA el arreglo : "));
var finalArreglo = Number(prompt("Escribe el elmento FINAL del arreglos : "));
var arregloVacio = [];

    function rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo) {
        for (i = inicioArreglo; i <= finalArreglo; i++) {
            arregloVacio.push(i);
        }
        console.log(arregloVacio);
    };
    rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo);
```

all good so the problem here is the output generated console me in google chrome I get this when I run the program for the first time this is the console output :

```
Array[5]
0: 2
1: 3
2: 4
3: 5
4: 6  

length: 5

__proto__ : Array[0]
```

but when reload the page I already appears the result I want in google chrome console:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: add your code to a fiddle, you'll get more responses http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add other `console.log` outside the function, like this.

```
function rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo) {
        for (i = inicioArreglo; i <= finalArreglo; i++) {
            arregloVacio.push(i);
        }
    console.log(arregloVacio);
    };
  console.log(arregloVacio);
     rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo);
```

And you will get the value from the array check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hunmbmr/)

if you want to make them to don't refresh try with this.

```
<body onunload="rango()">
```

Comment: the problem is not resolved get the result only if I reload the page, the first time I load the page again gives me this result:                       Array[5]
0: 2
1: 3
2: 4
3: 5
4: 6  
length: 5
__proto__ : Array[0]

Comment: awesome, i dont relly understand you problem, 1 question my answer was useful?

Comment: if my answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted if not tell me so i can delete it to don't confuse newcomers

Answer (score 0):

my solution the first time you load the page showing me the elements of array and no need to reload or refresh the page but the result is without brackets[] and print the array as a string :

```html
var inicioArreglo = Number(prompt("Escribe el elemento con el que INICIA el arreglo : "));
var finalArreglo = Number(prompt("Escribe el elemento FINAL del arreglos : "));
var arregloVacio = [];

function rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo) {
 for (i = inicioArreglo; i <= finalArreglo; i++) {
  arregloVacio.push(i);
 }
 console.log(arregloVacio.toString());
};
rango(inicioArreglo, finalArreglo);
```